# Concatenate and shift columns in pandas apply

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I am presented with a data frame that looks like the sample below

```
col_a col_b col_c col_d extra1 extra2 extra3
a     a     a     a     b      c      d 
a     a     a     a     b      c      d 
a     a     a     b     c      d      Nan 
a     a     a     b     c      d      Nan 
a     a     b     c     d      Nan    Nan
a     a     b     c     d      Nan    Nan  
a     b     c     d     Nan    Nan    Nan
a     b     c     d     Nan    Nan    Nan
```

I have to transform it into something like this:

```
col_a    col_b col_c col_d 
a a a a   b     c     d 
a a a a   b     c     d 
a a a     b     c     d       
a a a     b     c     d       
a a       b     c     d  
a a       b     c     d    
a         b     c     d    
a         b     c     d
```

Therefore it looks like depending on where the NaN is (extra1 2 or 3), I will always have to shift the last 3 cols before the column conining Nan and concatenate the prior columns into col_a.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
#if necessary convert string `Nan` to missing values
df = df.replace('Nan', np.nan)

df = df.apply(lambda x: x.shift(x.isnull().sum()), axis=1)
print (df)
  col_a col_b col_c col_d extra1 extra2 extra3
0     a     a     a     a      b      c      d
1     a     a     a     a      b      c      d
2   NaN     a     a     a      b      c      d
3   NaN     a     a     a      b      c      d
4   NaN   NaN     a     a      b      c      d
5   NaN   NaN     a     a      b      c      d
6   NaN   NaN   NaN     a      b      c      d
7   NaN   NaN   NaN     a      b      c      d

df1 = df.iloc[:, -3:]
df1.insert(0, 'a', df.iloc[:, :-3].add(' ').fillna('').sum(axis=1))
df1.columns = df.columns[:4]
print (df1)
      col_a col_b col_c col_d
0  a a a a      b     c     d
1  a a a a      b     c     d
2    a a a      b     c     d
3    a a a      b     c     d
4      a a      b     c     d
5      a a      b     c     d
6        a      b     c     d
7        a      b     c     d
```

Comment: it's looking good , however there is one problem, because in your case you have ... df.iloc[:, :-3].add('..., and this just replaces the first column values in all rows below`

Comment: @dre_84w934 are real data confidental?

Comment: yes it is confidential, heres a fix for the line above, if you change it, i will mark your answer as correct df1.insert(0, '_', value=df[df.columns[:-3]].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x.dropna().fillna('').astype(str)),axis=1))

Comment: another question I would have, is how  do you limit the shift only for na in the extra_columns?

Answer (score 2):

You could use itertools groupby, which is common for tasks with grouping. This will however use a loop (comprehension) which might impact the effectiveness.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data = [[' '.join(g) for k,g in groupby(row) if k] for row in df.fillna('').values],
    columns = df.columns[:4]
)
```

Full example:

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import groupby

data = '''\
col_a col_b col_c col_d extra1 extra2 extra3
a     a     a     a     b      c      d 
a     a     a     a     b      c      d 
a     a     a     b     c      d      Nan 
a     a     a     b     c      d      Nan 
a     a     b     c     d      Nan    Nan
a     a     b     c     d      Nan    Nan  
a     b     c     d     Nan    Nan    Nan
a     b     c     d     Nan    Nan    Nan'''

fileobj = pd.compat.StringIO(data)
df = pd.read_csv(fileobj, sep='\s+', na_values=['Nan'])

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data = [[' '.join(g) for k,g in groupby(row) if k] for row in df.fillna('').values],
    columns = df.columns[:4]
)

print(df)
```

Returns:

```
     col_a col_b col_c col_d
0  a a a a     b     c     d
1  a a a a     b     c     d
2    a a a     b     c     d
3    a a a     b     c     d
4      a a     b     c     d
5      a a     b     c     d
6        a     b     c     d
7        a     b     c     d
```

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
temp = df[['col_a','col_b','col_c','col_d']].eq("a").sum(axis=1)
print(temp)

v = []
for i in temp:
    a_col =  "a"*i
    v.append(a_col)

df['col_a'] = v
df['col_b'] = 'b'
df['col_c'] = 'c'
df['col_d'] = 'd'

df.drop(['ex_1','ex_2','ex_3'],1,inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  col_a col_b col_c col_d
0  aaaa     b     c     d
1  aaaa     b     c     d
2   aaa     b     c     d
3   aaa     b     c     d
4    aa     b     c     d
5    aa     b     c     d
6     a     b     c     d
7     a     b     c     d
```

Comment: "a" is a sample data, my actual data does not actually contain "a", but names and other info. So I cannot use your code in my case